# How to store, fetch and edit form data in html without using database?

Tags: html

I have an html form and i want to store fetch and edit this form data **without** using database like phpmyadmin etc. How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML doesn't have that capability, but you can use Javascript to access & edit form data before submit. Ex:

```
/* jQuery example */
$('#form').submit( function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* manipulate data here */ });
```

Storage on the other hand is usually done on the server side and involves a database, like php and mysql for example.

Comment: we can store on client side as well using indexed DB